# How to use the AJAX with DJANGO appropriately?

Tags: django, ajax, coding-style, dry

I am a newbie in web dev and I know how to use the AJAX with DJANGO but i want to know what method is going to be the best one i use the script tags within my html files because they allow me to use DTL for urls but the time when use them I feel I'm doing something bad about design. Any guidelines what is standard way of writing a clean code which will be more usable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below structure and
include Js from external folders

```
<script src="{% static 'app/js/app.js' %}"></script>
```

[image]